# I cannot install silverstripe 4

Tags: installation, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm trying to install on my VPS, LAMP technology, SS 4.01 but I have an error. I already have 3 websites made on 3.x SS that are working.

Installing SilverStripe...
I am now running through the installation steps (this should take about 30 seconds)

If you receive a fatal error, refresh this page to continue the installation

```
Setting up /home/devsquala/public_html/index.php
Setting up /home/devsquala/public_html/mysite/_config.php
Setting up /home/devsquala/public_html/mysite/_config/theme.yml
Setting up /home/devsquala/public_html/.env
Setting up /home/devsquala/public_html/.htaccess
Building database schema...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/devsquala/public_html/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 727
ERROR [Warning]: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' IN POST /~devsquala/install.php Line 727 in /home/devsquala/public_html/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php Source ====== 718: if (!is_writable($dir)) { 719: throw new IOException(sprintf('Unable to write to the "%s" directory.', $dir), 0, null, $dir); 720: } 721: 722: if (false === @file_put_contents($filename, $content, FILE_APPEND)) { 723: throw new IOException(sprintf('Failed to write file "%s".', $filename), 0, null, $filename); 724: } 725: } 726: * 727: private function toIterable($files): iterable 728: { 729: return is_array($files) || $files instanceof \Traversable ? $files : array($files); 730: } 731: 732: /** 733: * Gets a 2-tuple of scheme (may be null) and hierarchical part of a filename (e.g. file:///tmp -> array(file, tmp)). Trace ===== SilverStripe\Dev\CliDebugView->renderTrace() DetailedErrorFormatter.php:117 SilverStripe\Logging\DetailedErrorFormatter->output(4, syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{', /home/devsquala/public_html/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php, 727, ) DetailedErrorFormatter.php:53 SilverStripe\Logging\DetailedErrorFormatter->format(Array) AbstractProcessingHandler.php:35 Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) Logger.php:337 Monolog\Logger->addRecord(550, Fatal Error (E_PARSE): syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{', Array) Logger.php:518 Monolog\Logger->log(alert, Fatal Error (E_PARSE): syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{', Array) ErrorHandler.php:181 Monolog\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
```

Answer (score 3):

This error happens because the packaged installer you've used from the SilverStripe website was built for PHP 7, and contains dependencies that are compatible with PHP 7 but not PHP 5 (which you're using).

You can track this issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/7709

To fix it, remove the `vendor` folder in your project and recreate it using `composer update`.